# Instagram API - Manually get the 'tag_id' of an image

Tags: jquery, ajax, instagram

Using the tag endpoint, the returned 'Pagination' object gives me the next_max_tag_id and min_tag_id to easily paginate, but how do I manually get the tag id for a specific image?

For instance, I'm requesting 25 images via AJAX, but only displaying the first 10 (since Instagram doesn't ignore private images when listening to 'count'). But I'm hoping to use a custom next_max_tag_id using the id of the 10th image I'm displaying.

Better question - what is the 'next_max_tag_id'?

Any help?

Comment: Any chance of a jsfiddle.net demo of what you are doing? I tried to follow your question, but it's just not jelling in my head.